# How to give ID to the li that contain selected text?

Tags: jquery

I have this ol list

```
<ol><li class="first"><a href="/ivory/node/183">Sour Candy Spray 8.5ml (3 flavors)</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/181">Chap Ice Mini Stick 3g (Cherry)</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/180">Chap Ice Mini Stick 3g (Kiwi)</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/179">Chap Ice Mini Stick 3g (Orange)</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="/ivory/node/166">Chap Ice Beeswax</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/165">Chap Ice Cherry Stick</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/170">Chap Ice Crazy Flavors 4.2g (Blueraspberry)</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/169">Chap Ice Crazy Flavors 4.2g (Watermelon)</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/168">Chap Ice Crazy Flavors Verry Berry 4.2g</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/167">Chap Ice Moisture 4.2g Stick</a></li>
<li><a href="/ivory/node/164">Chap Ice Original 4.2g Stick</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="/ivory/node/163">ChapIce 10G Petrolium Jelly Squeeze Tube</a></li>
</ol>
```

How to find the li that contain "Chap Ice Cherry Stick" and give it a unique ID?

Comment: I tried this code
if($("li a").html("Chap Ice Beeswax")){
this.parent().addClass("selected");
}

Comment: @Chanckjh This is help website. If you have a million of reputation you will not earn a prize.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$('li a:contains("Chap Ice Cherry Stick")').parent().attr('id', youruniqueID)
```

If you expect more then one elements to appear

```
$('li a:contains("Chap Ice Cherry Stick")').each(function(index, elem){
   $(this).parent().attr('id', "chap" + index);
})
```

Comment: $('li a:contains("Chap Ice Cherry Stick")').parent().attr("id", "youruniqueID");

Comment: I thought you want to assign id to a but in li. I have updated my answer to assign to li, thanks.